# GoogleCloud browser refresh issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Let me start off by saying I'm not a developer, coder, or engineer. I use googlecloud to host a staging site to show clients html5 animations for review. About a year ago googlecloud changed something and whenever I make revisions to my htm5 banners and repost them to googlecloud it takes up to an hour for the revision to refresh in any browser. Is there a setting in googleCloud that will refresh new files instantly instead of telling the client they have to wait an hour to see revisions? Like I said a year ago I didn't have this issue all updates were instant. I know I can just go and change the file name but I don't want to rename the file every time I make a revision.

Answer (score 0):

As said in this answer [How to Quickly Update Static Site on Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661116/how-to-quickly-update-static-site-on-google-cloud-storage/45686299#45686299)

It's more likely you're looking at a cache effect. Which can happen:

- inside the Google cloud:

  - work around it using a made up extra URL query parameter, like `?ignoreCache=1`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37124554/4495081, or
  - see [Cache-Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#cache-control) and [Editing object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#edit) if you want a more permanent solution (but which also affects your site's performance, so think twice about what you're doing)
- in your browser - try clearing your browser's cache after deployments
- pretty much anywhere in between (and you have no control over this).

---

Or in this question [Missing a step to update a static ReactJS site on GCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032160/missing-a-step-to-update-a-static-reactjs-site-on-gcloud/50184240#50184240)

This is how I was able to update my static site on gcloud using the command line utility.

- Create a new bucket, ideally name it with a version like appname-v2
- Copy your recent build into that bucket
- Delete the old bucket
- From your main area in your console where you see your app's directory do `gsutil rsync -r gs://[bucketname] ./appname`
- `cd` into the directory
- run `gcloud app deploy`

So if your latest version of your app is 3, if your app's directory is stackoverflow, and your bucket is "bucket" then your gsutil command would look like

```
gsutil rsync -r gs://bucket-v3 ./stackoverflow
```